Javascript Textarea prevent Alt gr + key combinations on KeyDown/KeyUp events itself
In my text area im using onKeydown event to listen to characters typed by user.
I need to prevent Alt gr + key combination values (ē, r̥, ṭ,...) to avoid accented keys in my text area.
if (event.code === 'AltRight')  {
      console.log('Prevent Accent letters');
      event.preventDefault();
    }

(or)

if (event.code === 17 || event.code === 18)  {
      console.log('Prevent Accent letters');
      event.preventDefault();
    }

Nothing worked. They are entering these if condition but still the accent text is getting printed in my textarea. How can this be prevented

We need to create a custom directive which works with the regex /[\\x00-\\x7F]*/i to negate all the alt code characters, and only filters out the valid ones, we can use match to do this!
Alt Codes wiki
Article used for deriving this answer
Regexr to check the regex
SIMPLE VERSION:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { PermitDirective } from './app/input.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [PermitDirective],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <textarea (input)="onInputChange($event)"></textarea>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  onInputChange(event: any) {
    event.target.value = event.target.value.match(/[\\x00-\\x7F]*/i).toString();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

COMPLEX VERSION (works for paste also):
directive
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPermit]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class PermitDirective {
  @Input('regex') pattern: RegExp = /[\\x00-\\x7F]*/i;

  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInput(e: any) {
    e.target.value = this.isValidText(e, '');
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste(event: any) {
    return this.isValidText(event, event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
  }

  isValidText(e: any, text: any) {
    debugger;
    const [selectionStart, selectionEnd] = this.getSelectionRange(e.target);
    // for elements not having value accessor(innerText)
    const existingValue = e.target.value ?? e.target.innerText;
    console.log(
      e.target.value,
      'typed',
      existingValue.substring(0, selectionStart) +
        text +
        existingValue.substring(selectionEnd)
    );
    return (
      existingValue.substring(0, selectionStart) +
      text +
      existingValue.substring(selectionEnd)
    )
      .match(this.pattern)
      .toString();
  }

  getSelectionRange(el: HTMLElement) {
    if (el instanceof HTMLInputElement || el instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement) {
      // These properties aren't present for any HTMLElement
      return [el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd];
    }
    // currently getSelection() doesn't work on the content of <textarea> and // <input> elements in Firefox, Edge (Legacy)
    const { startOffset, endOffset } = <any>getSelection()?.getRangeAt(0);
    return [startOffset, endOffset];
  }
}

main.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { PermitDirective } from './app/input.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [PermitDirective],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <textarea appPermit></textarea>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

But i simple want to restrict the Alt + gr key combinations on keydown so as to prevent Accent keys. How can that be achieved

ok Naren got it. Other workaround. Can we capture the final output text of this Alt gr + key combination before it being added to innetText. Because i need to allow these accent keys at certain point. Not completely avoid them.

@PriyaGanesan Yes, you can use the regex "asdfasdf123☻".match(/[^\x00-\x7F]/i) to do that!

Thanks, The above code does not completely cover my purpose. When my character limit is reached 999 out of 1000 i have to prevent further Alt gr + key value being added. How can i prevent Alt gr key operation ?

Implemented above code and when accent keys given (æ,ē,ṭ,ū.. ) isValid returns empty. But for r̥ (alt gr+r) it does not work. isValid returns r character.
